# Find unused modules in nodeJS outside package.json

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have to document and resume code from another developer which has been fired because of a lot a disciplinary trouble inside the team.

The application uses nodeJS and mongoDB and I'm a beginner at nodeJS, but webstorm help me a lot to understand how the application works.

(I precise the former dev did not leave me so much documentation, so I'm doing reverse engeeniring and cleaning here).

My question today is:

the node_modules looks like it is really huge to me, with 243 sub-repository. I'm suspecting than some of these are not usefull to the project but the package.json is not really helping here:

```
{
"name": "my_rotting_project",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "main.js",
"bin": "main.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --no-deprecation core/server",
    "server": "nodemon --no-deprecation core/server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "luna": "file:./core"
},
"pkg": {
    "scripts": "plugins/**/*.js",
    "assets": [
        "static/**/*",
        "core/static/**/*"
    ]
},
"nodemonConfig": {
    "ext": "js,mjs,json,html,css,ejs"
}
```

}

I have launched `npx check` and `npx npm_check` commands but they show me no unused library which seems unlikely (but both of them have written than some of dependencies was missing in package.json)

Does someone know if theses plugins are reliable enough or should I try other methods ? (and what should I do in this case ?)

thank you !